# TWS earbud out to RCA low volume and noisy. Is an amplifier needed?

Tags: audio

I have TWS earbuds that use a QCC3020 chip.  I connected the speaker output of each bud to an RCA connector of an active monitor speaker, but the speaker very noisy and low volume.  Is a small amplifier needed?

I heard that I should that never use an amplifier with an active speaker.

Here is what I tested the TWS output with:

- Bud -> RCA: very noisy and low volume
- Bud -> earbud driver: normal
- Bud -> 2 pin of 3.5 mm connector -> small bluetooth speaker: low volume, a bit noisy

[image]

What should I do to get the RCA output to work?

I added some extra info. The earbud are "Haylou GT1 XR."

I snapped some more pictures.

I didn't do much just soldered on a bigger battery and replaced the speaker out with a connector for easier testing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the output does not come directly from the QCC3020 chip, but most likely there's a D-class H-bridge amplifer meant to drive a speaker. If you shorted the speaker negatives together that will not work. But impossible to say if this is the case as you haven't given any info which specific module it is and a link to manual for reading what kind of output it has.

Comment: How do you know it is the QCC3020 causing the problem? That part does not give a lot of audio power. Is it possible you have blown the speaker or the QCC3020? There is an old saying garbage in amplification = more garbage out. Check the quality of the input signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the Bud -> RCA -> a small test amplifier and thing is good now, no more noise, I will get a low power mono amplifier board for this setup

Comment: You may find that a small audio transformer works well, without the need for an amplifier.